# Logstash Output Index Yearly Rotation

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Quick question related to Logstash and Elasticsearch:

If I use the following output index option:

```
index => "myindex-%{+MM}"
```

Will this overwrite the oldest index once it reaches a year or just add to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash will never delete existing indexes, so when the year ends, the oldest index will be used again.

Nothing will get overwritten **AS LONG AS** the document ids of new documents are always different than the ids of the documents already existing in that index.